# How can I test whether browser support loading='lazy'?

Tags: javascript

Browser level Lazyload is a new feature(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)for almost all browser.

I wanna test whether the browser supports it, if not then add the polyfill([https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill#:~:text=loading%3D%22lazy%22%20attribute%20polyfill,not%20just%20thatfor%20%2D%20SEO%20friendly.](https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill#:%7E:text=loading%3D%22lazy%22%20attribute%20polyfill,not%20just%20thatfor%20%2D%20SEO%20friendly.)) for it.

How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google recommends](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#how-do-i-handle-browsers-that-don%27t-yet-support-lazy-loading):

```
if ('loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype) {
  // supported in browser
} else {
  // fetch polyfill/third-party library
}
```